# How reverse singly linked list in Pascal?

Tags: list, pascal, singly-linked-list, freepascal

```
program uka3;
type
    itemptr = ^item;
    item = record
        data: integer;
        next: itemptr;
    end;

var
    first, tmp: itemptr;
    n: integer;
begin
    first := nil;
    while not SeekEof do { Reading numbers }
    begin
        read(n);
        new(tmp);
        tmp^.data := n;
        tmp^.next := first;
        first := tmp;
    end;

{ here i need loop that reverse number in right order } 

    tmp := first;
    while tmp <> nil do { Output reversed numbers }
    begin
        writeln(tmp^.data);
        tmp := tmp^.next;
    end;

    while first <> nil do { Free memory }
    begin
        tmp := first^.next;
        dispose(first);
        first := tmp;
    end;
end.
```

This program read numbers and output them in reverse order.

How i can reverse these numbers in a loop after reading them so that they go in order which they were written?

Comment: You could store the numbers as they are displayed into another stack then display the contents of that stack - they will come out again in reverse order that will actually be the original order.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a procedure which reverses the list. Simply call it with *ReverseList*(*first*).

```
procedure ReverseList(var list: itemptr);
    var curr, prev, next: itemptr;
begin
    prev := nil;
    curr := list;
    while curr <> nil do
    begin
        next := curr^.next;
        curr^.next := prev;
        prev := curr;
        curr := next
    end;
    list := prev
end
```

Comment: bro i have singly linked list) I reversed it with another stack

Comment: @17sean *ReverseList* expects a single-linked list. This is the most efficient way to reverse a single-linked list.